# Conditional compile based on Xcode version

Tags: xcode, swift

I've built a plug-in for Xcode that primarily gets deployed through Alcatraz. This utility grabs the source for my plug-in from GitHub, compiles it, and, if successful, installs it in the proper directory. It has worked quite well until version 7.3 of Xcode was released with Swift 2.2.

Swift 2.2 introduced a new way of specifying selectors. Previously you would supply a string with the name of the function such as this:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver( self, selector: "applicationFinishedLoading:", name: NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil )
```

However the new method uses the #selector like so:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ColorSenseRainbow.applicationFinishedLoading(_:)), name: NSApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification, object: nil )
```

If I convert my code over to the new method then any people that are using previous versions of Xcode (7.2.1 and older) won't be able to use my plug-in because it doesn't know about the new #selector. I know this because I did convert it to get rid of the deprecation warnings and I got feedback from my users. However it is probable that the next version of Xcode will move to Swift 3 and I will have to make this change.

So my preferable path is to find a way to have the compiler choose the code applicable for the version of Xcode.  Something like this pseudo-code.

```
#if (XCode_Version >= 7.3)
    // use @selector ( ThisClass.functionName)
#else
    // use selector: "functionName:"
#endif
```

I know that there is swift() function that can be used to tell the version but that was only introduced with Swift 2.2 and if I use that the compilation will fail on Xcode 7.2.1 and below. This leaves me in the same place as before with the @selector function.

The other option is to take the release that I'm about to do and make it the last one with the selector: "functionName:" method. I'll then have a copy of that pre-compiled up on GitHub for users of older versions of Xcode to download and install manually.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maintaining legacy support on a language currently in development seems ill advised. There's little to gain from this, there's no reason not to be on the latest Xcode/Swift version.

Comment: I'm on the latest Xcode/Swift but the plug-in code is downloaded and compiled by hundreds of people across the world.  I am unable to dictate their choice in development environment and so I would like to be able to support them if possible. They may have good reasons for not moving off of an application that is less than a year old.  I'm talking about supporting Xcode 7.2.1 not version 4.

Comment: Swift, as a language itself, is under heavy development. Nothing is set in stone, and many things are moving along quickly, even things as basic as the `Array` literal syntax. Anybody who wants to write swift understand Source code and ABI instability will exist, to a great extent, for the next little while. Supporting something that is nonsensical.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this issue, and this is how I solved it.

Xcode exports the environment variable `XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL` which is the current version of Xcode in the format `0910` for instance in Xcode 9.1. It's possible to utilize this to create a compilation flag for conditional compilation.

In your project settings, create a build setting like `XCODE_0910_COMPILATION_FLAGS` and set it to `-DXCODE_VERSION_9_1`. Then, in Other Swift Flags add `$(XCODE_$(XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL)_COMPILATION_FLAGS)` which will conditionally bring in the compilation flag.

Then in code, it should be possible to do something like:

```
#if XCODE_VERSION_9_1
  // do something conditional to Xcode 9.1
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift supports conditional compiling, you can set your own conditions.

Use something like `#if SWIFT_2_0` and define `-D SWIFT_2_0` in a project that has to use an older version of Swift.